# checkbox check/uncheck using d3

Tags: javascript, checkbox, d3.js

I am having difficulty checking and unchecking checkboxes using d3 selection. The following code doesn't seem to work. I want all check boxes to be checked when 'check' is pressed, and all checkboxes unchecked when 'uncheck' is pressed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<button type='button' onclick='checkAll()'>Check</button>
<button type='button' onclick='uncheckAll()'>Uncheck</button>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js?2.10.0"></script>

<script>
function checkAll(){
    d3.selectAll('input').attr('checked','true');
}
function uncheckAll(){
    d3.selectAll('input').attr('checked','false');
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 41):

Use `property()` instead of `attr()`:

```
function checkAll() {
    d3.selectAll('input').property('checked', true);
}
function uncheckAll() {
    d3.selectAll('input').property('checked', false);
}
```

From https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-property:

> Some HTML elements have special properties that are not addressable using standard attributes or styles. For example, form text fields have a `value` string property, and **checkboxes have a `checked` boolean property**. You can use the `property` operator to get or set these properties.

Answer (score 4):

You can limit your selection to only checkboxes by filtering the selection on the type attribute,

```
d3.selectAll("input[type=checkbox]").property("checked", true);
```

This avoids setting the checked attribute on non-checkbox inputs that are present.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `uncheckAll` function to set the `checked` attributes to `null` instead of `false`:

```
function uncheckAll(){
    d3.selectAll('input').attr('checked',null);
}
```

The checked attribute is either present, optionally set to `checked="checked"`, or absent (no checked attribute at all).  Setting it to `null` will remove the attribute, in this case.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is update the checked value of the element as follows:

```
d3.selectAll("input").each(function(d){ 
  if(d3.select(this).attr("type") == "checkbox") 
    d3.select(this).node().checked = true;
});
```

This will ensure only all checkbox states are changed