# Get value property of each element in d3 selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a lot of input tags for the following form:

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="something_I_need_when_checked">
```

I need the value of all the checked boxes. When I call `console.log(d3.selectAll("input.checkbox:checked").property("value"))` I only see the value of the first element. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849738/checkbox-check-uncheck-using-d3/20204162#20204162) post had some leads on how to change these values (EDIT: I don't want to change anything; I just want the values). I tried using the `selection.each(function())` idea that was suggested but I didn't get me anywhere. How can I get all values in my selection.

I'm a n00b, be nice. Thanks ~

Answer (score 2):

`selection.each` does work. However, you have to call it **after** clicking the checkboxes.

In this demo, the selection will be created **after** you click the button named "Check". Click the boxes you want, and after that click the button:

```js
d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
  var boxes = d3.selectAll("input.checkbox:checked");
  boxes.each(function() {
    console.log(this.value)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="foo">foo
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="bar">bar
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="baz">baz
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="foobar">foobar
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="foobaz">foobaz
<button>Check</button>
```

EDIT: storing the checked values in an array:

```js
var checked = [];
d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
  var boxes = d3.selectAll("input.checkbox:checked");
  boxes.each(function() {
    checked.push(this.value)
  });
  console.log(checked)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="foo">foo
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="bar">bar
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="baz">baz
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="foobar">foobar
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="foobaz">foobaz
<button>Check</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had boxes check. I was trying to use something like `selection.each(function(d) { return d.property("value")})`; it threw errors. It's good to know that I don't need to use .property()`

Comment: `d` will not work because there is no data bound to those elements.

Comment: One last question: how can I store them in an array? or can I access them some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the fields into an array is to use the `map` function.  In the example below, I build off of Gerardo Furtado's answer.

```js
d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
  var checkedBoxes = d3.selectAll("input.checkbox:checked").nodes().map(box => box.value);
  console.log(checkedBoxes)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="foo">foo
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="bar">bar
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="baz">baz
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="foobar">foobar
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="foobaz">foobaz
<button>Check</button>
```